# Perfectly Center lightbox dynamically no matter screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pop-up div that is able to stream video or show a document/image depending on the file attachment.

The issue I'm having is ensuring that it is centered vertically and horizontally, both for Desktop and mobile browsers/app.

I've been trying different attributes, but it's like I change from what I already have and suddenly it's just off the page.

```
if(extension === "mp4"){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="light"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();">x</a><video id="VideoLauncher" width="600" controls controlsList="nodownload"><source src="'+file+' " type="video/mp4"><!--Browser does not support <video> tag --></video></div><div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>'
}
if(extension === "jpg"){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="light"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();">x</a><img id="VideoLauncher" width="600"  src="'+file+'" onclick="lightbox_close()"></img></div><div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>'
}
if(extension === "pdf" || extension === "doc" || extension === "docx"){
    document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="light"><a class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="lightbox_close();">x</a><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url='+file+'&embedded=true" style="height:800px; width:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe></div><div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>'
}

var LightEle = document.querySelector("#light");
var FadeEle = document.querySelector("#fade");
var BoxCloseEle = document.querySelector("#boxclose");

LightEle.style.cssText = 'display: none;  position: absolute; top: 50%;  left: 50%;  max-width: 600px;  max-height: 100%px;  margin-left: -200px;  margin-top: -180px;  border: 2px solid #FFF;  background: #FFF;  z-index: 1002;  overflow: visible;';
FadeEle.style.cssText = 'display: none;  position: fixed;  top: 0%;  left: 0%;  width: 100%;  height: 100%;  background-color: black;  z-index: 1001;  -moz-opacity: 0.8;  opacity: .80;  filter: alpha(opacity=80);';
```

Ideally, what I'm looking for is the styling that will dynamically center the light element, horizontally and vertically, though the light element will be a different size depending on the file it is to show. Because of this I can't simply hard code the height and width.

Comment: Wrapper needs `display:flex` and content needs `margin: auto`. Add some max-width and max-height to the inner box and it should scale perfectly in almost all browser (but seeing that you are using the `alpha(opacity=80)` I fear you are trying to support very old browsers. In that case, just calculate with JS)

Comment: Yeah as @somethinghere said these approaches will always work, in modern browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to doing this:

```css
.lightbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This only centers horizontally within the parent component. It is a very simple way if that's what you want to do.

If not, try this:

```
.lightbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: the margin: 0 auto did not work for me, however the other suggested worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

A popular approach to vertically **and** horizontally center elements is to use:

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
```

You can use this with *absolute* or *fixed* positioning . `top` and `left` moves the top left corner to the center of the screen while `translate( -50%, -50% )` moves the element back to the left and top 50% of the elements width/height, placing the center of the element at the center of the page.

```css
.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50% );
  
  /* For Demo */
  width: 75vw;
  height: 75vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox:

```css
main {
  background-color: teal;
}

.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}

.modal {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 300px;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <h2>yes</h2>

    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```